# How to receive touch from two buttons in the same time with cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, button, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem, ccmenu

I'm working with cocos2d now and I've got some menu.

```
menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btnMenu, nil];
```

I've got method to handle taps. `btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4` are in the same menu and every button has the same method to handle taps. On Cocoa Touch it's working correctly: 4 buttons tapped in one time - four taps received. With cocos2d: four buttons tapped - one received.

Where is the problem, and how can i do this correctly?

Comment: How do you manage to tap 4 buttons at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create different menu.

```
menu1 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:btn1, btn2, nil];
menu2 = [CCMenu menuWithItems: btn3, btn4, nil];
```